# Populate JTable with strings from JTextFields

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

I am building a GUI for MySQL, with JFrames with collaboration with jdbc.
I am not that good in Java and I can't figure the following out.

I want to populate a JTable with data from a query of mine, but I want this query to have user parameters inside. So..

Here is the query:

```
 String sql = "SELECT `field1`, `field2`, `field3`"
            + "FROM `Table1` INNER JOIN `Table2` on `table1PK` = `table2PK`"
            + "WHERE `column1Value` = '"+JTextfield1.getText()+'" AND"
            + " `column2Value` = '"+JTextfield2.getText()+"'";
```

And then, with the output of this string, after pressing a JButton, I want to populate a JTable.

In other words I want the "output" of the JTable to be "UserParameterDefined" (through the JTextFields)

Here is the hole code for a working auto-populating JTable but without User Defined Parameters which I have and works perfectly:

```
package pkginterface;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.*;

public class Movies_Info extends JFrame
{
    public Movies_Info()
{
    ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    //  Connect to an MySQL Database, run query, get result set
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cinema";
    String userid = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String sql = "SELECT movie_title, timetable_starttime, timetable_movietype "
            + "FROM Movies INNER JOIN TimeTable on timetable_movie_ID = movie_ID";

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userid, password );
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ))
    {
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        //  Get column names
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            columnNames.add( md.getColumnName(i) );
        }

        //  Get row data
        while (rs.next())
        {
            ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
            }

            data.add( row );
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }

    Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
    Vector dataVector = new Vector();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
        Vector subVector = new Vector();
        for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
        {
            subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
        }
        dataVector.add(subVector);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ )
        columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));

    //  Create table with database data    
    JTable table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)
    {
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            setTitle("Staff Interface - Movies Info");
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    // Time shown correction
   SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
           Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    if( value instanceof Time) {
        value = f.format(value);
    }
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
            hasFocus, row, column);
    }
  };
  table.setDefaultRenderer(Time.class, tableCellRenderer);
  // Time shown correction finish
    pack();

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Movies_Info frame = new Movies_Info();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: You'll want to learn and use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) with your queries

Comment: You'll also want to have a closer look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: I do...its just not needed in the above example. If I wasn't using a ps or a rs I think I wouldn't be able to login in mysql(with specific users) at all

Comment: *"I do...its just not needed in the above example"* - It's always needed. *"If I want using a ps or a rs I think I wouldn't be able to login in mysql(with specific users) at all"* - Doesn't make sense

Comment: You'll probably also want to have a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and 
[How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: I mean that my problem is not the lack of knowledge about using a ps a rs with collaboration with conn. Its that I can't understand how to call a builder of the JTbale frame, by sending among the 'call', user's input from jtextfield...I think that is kinda java basic knowledge that keeps me in the dark here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic concept would look something like...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;
        private JTable table;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            field = new JTextField(20);
            table = new JTable();

            add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JButton update = new JButton("Update");
            add(update, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        TableModel model = executeQueryWith(field.getText());
                        table.setModel(model);
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Failed to execute query", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected TableModel executeQueryWith(String value) throws SQLException {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cinema";
            String userid = "root";
            String password = "root";
            String sql = "SELECT movie_title, timetable_starttime, timetable_movietype "
                    + "FROM Movies INNER JOIN TimeTable on timetable_movie_ID = ?";

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, password)) {
                try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                    stmt.setString(1, value);
                    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

                        //  Get column names
                        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                            model.addColumn(md.getColumnName(i));
                        }

                        //  Get row data
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            Vector<Object> row = new Vector(columns);
                            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                                row.add(rs.getObject(i));
                            }
                            model.addRow(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return model;
        }

    }

}
```

You might also like to have a look at:

- [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)
- [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)